# What does the `throws IOExeption` do?

Tags: java

What does the `throws IOExeption` actually do when importing a file?

### Example

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Location"));
    // more code
    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [Lesson: Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: Additional: `throws` isn't always necessary, you could just as well put the code in a try/catch block

Comment: [JLS 8.4.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.6).

Answer (score 2):

`throws` indicates that a method requires a caller to either handle the exception, or allow the exception to continue being thrown up the call stack. The former requires the method that can throw the exception to be called in a *try-catch* block; the latter requires the calling method to include the type of exception (e.g. `IOException`) in its own method signature.

In your case, `main(String[] args)` includes the exception in its signature, meaning it does not plan on handling the exception but instead will pass it up the stack. Since main is the program's entry point, there is nothing else to handle the exception and the program would terminate.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the IO classes throws a checked exception called `IOException`, e.g. saying "File not found". A checked exception must be handled in a try-catch block or it must be allowed to bubble up to the caller of your method by declaring that your method may cause that exception to be raised.

In your book, there's no need to handle exceptions, so simply allowing the exception to bubble up is the easiest to do. You'll learn more about this later.

Answer (score 1):

The `throws IOExeption` actually does not do anything when "importing" the file. Rather, it is relevant to what happens when you *fail* to "import" the file.

The [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File)) class throws an [`IOException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) when the file could not be read for some reason. However, `IOException` is a [**checked** exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation). This means that Java demands that you handle the exception somehow in a [`try/catch` block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html).

When you declare `throws IOException`, you are telling Java that you will *not* handle the exception, and instead allow it to bubble up, and leave the caller of your method to handle the exception instead.

In this particular case, you are already in the `main` method. So you will get a stack trace should be exception be thrown.

Comment: So, then I should be able to import files without using throws `throws IOExeption` as long as the file exists and I have not made any errors with the name?

Comment: @newplayer12132 Yes. If you think the file exists for sure, say like 'Program Files'' system files, then yeah just go ahead with throws. But still it's good practice to handle it by yourself. At least have a logger that says that file doesn't exist.

Comment: All this 'import the file'/'fail to import the file' business is meaningless.

Comment: @EJP My justification is that in the original revision of this question there was this line: `it says that you have to use throws IOExeption to input the file. What I want to know is what does the throws IOExeption actually do when importing a file.` It appeared as if the original poster thought that `throws IOException` did something to the importing of the file. Which is why I added that line as a clarification.

Answer (score -1):

When you are stating that a method throws an exception you are actually saying that the code that is outside (the caller or his ancestors in the callstack) this method is the one that's gonna need to catch the exception (and maybe no one)
also, in your method, youre gonna need to use "`throw`" key word.

for example, a case when the calling code **IS** catching the thrown execption:

```
class example
{
   static void method() throws IOExeption 
   {
     // in this code section you use the Scanner and from inside its code an
     // an IOExeption is thrown ( using "throw IOExecption;")
   } 
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       try
       {
          method();
       }
       catch (IOExeption ioe)
       {
          // handle it however you want
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: No you're not. You don't know who's going to catch it. Maybe nobody. Maybe it percolates out of `main()`. But you're going to throw it. So the calling code has to be written accordingly.